# Select from two outer joined tables where a possible null column

Tags: mysql, left-join, outer-join

Question similar to this:

[select from two tables where linked column can be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763922/select-from-two-tables-where-linked-column-can-be-null)

```
column1tab1 column2tab1 order_number product amount
 xx            yy            123      p1      2
 xx            yy            456      p3      4
 xx            yy            NULL    NULL    NULL
 xx            yy            789      p2      1
 etc...
```

The poster's output was like above. However, when I add in WHERE `product` = 'p1', or alternatively WHERE `product` = NULL both return an empty set. Eventually, I want to have

```
SELECT            *
FROM              `t1`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `t2`
  ON              (`t1`.`id` = `t2`.`id2`)
WHERE             `t2`.`product` = NULL
  AND             `t2`.`product` <> 'p1'
```

Which part am I doing wrong? The join or the where? Or something else?

Comment: `product = NULL` would be `product IS NULL`, but beside that a null value automatically makes the second `product <> 'p1'` truthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
`t2`.`product` = NULL
```

with

```
`t2`.`product` IS NULL
```

[See here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null)

Answer (score 1):

`t2.product = NULL` is always false. Use `t2.product IS NULL` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If t2.product is null it is always different from the string 'p1'. I don't see the need for the and.